# Silverlight 4: image in datatemplate not appearing on design surface

Tags: silverlight, image, binding, datatemplate, designer

I'm trying to bind an image's source to a string in a listbox with a data template.

When I run the application, I see the image in the browser, but I cannot see it on the design surface.

Any ideas?

I have created a sample user control with a 3-row grid. 
In row 0 i just put the image 
In row 1 i put the image into a listbox item
In row 2 I put the image into a datatemplate in a listbox bound to a resource

On the design surface, I can see the image in rows 0 and 1, but not in row 2.

```
public class PersonCollection : List<Person>
{
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string PictureURL { get; set; }
}
```

```xml
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <mystuff:PersonCollection x:Key="PersonList">
            <mystuff:Person Name="Rick" PictureURL="abc.jpg"/>
            <mystuff:Person Name="Bob" PictureURL="abc.jpg"/>
        </mystuff:PersonCollection>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Image Source="abc.jpg"/>
    <ListBox Grid.Row="1">
        <ListBoxItem>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="abc.jpg"/>                    
            </StackPanel>
        </ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
    <ListBox Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{StaticResource PersonList}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Source="{Binding PictureURL}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: The designer I'm talking about is the VS Web Developer Express SP1 IDE, not blend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I defined the PictureUrl property as an ImageSource in the Person class, the designer in the VS IDE showed the image.

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ImageSource PictureURL { get; set; }
}

Here's where I got the information from:

http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/231544/568130.aspx#568130

Answer (score 0):

Just change the Person.Name Property to something else

Comment: Hi Waleed, the Person.Name is not the problem. The problem is related to the pictureurl